# Showing that the natural numbers are totally ordered with respect to set membership

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, induction, set-theory, natural-numbers

Working with the usual set theoretic construction of the natural numbers, denoted $\omega$ for now.

I am trying to show that $\omega$ is totally ordered with respect to set membership, that is, $n<m$ if and only if $n\in m$ is a total ordering on $\omega$. I can show irreflexivity and transitivity, but I am struggling to show totality.

Here is an attempt using induction:

Fix $m\in\omega$. Define $W=\{n\in\omega:[n \neq m\Longrightarrow (n\in m)\vee (m\in n)]\vee n=m\}$.

If $m=\emptyset$, then $\emptyset\in W$. If $m\neq\emptyset$, then $\emptyset\in m$ so $\emptyset\in W$.

Suppose that $n\in W$ for some $n\in\omega$. Now either $m=n\cup\{n\}$ or $m\neq n\cup\{n\}$. If $m=n\cup\{n\}$, then $n\cup\{n\}\in W$.

Otherwise, $n\cup\{n\}\neq m$.

If $n=m$, then $m\in n\cup\{n\}$ so $n\cup\{n\}\in W$.

If $n\neq m$, then $n\in m$ or $m\in n$. If $m\in n$, then $m\in n\cup\{n\}$. If $n\in m$, then $n\subset m$ and $\{n\}\subseteq m$ so $n\cup\{n\}\subset m$.

This is as far as I can get. I have been unable to show that $n\subset m$ implies $n\in m$, so my proof comes to a halt at the last case. If I had that fact, then I would be able to say $n\cup\{n\}\in m$ which would complete the proof. Trying to show that fact inductively has felt more difficult than it should be. What else would I need to show in order to complete the proof, or what other route could I take to show that set membership totally orders $\omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if the following form of induction is compatible with your construction, but here we go.

---

Curiously, I needed the following lemma which is the exact converse of the goal. If you already know its proof, feel free to skip it.

**Lemma**: For natural numbers $m,n, n\in m\Rightarrow n\subset m$. (In fact $n$ can be any set)

*Proof*: Induct on $m$. Obviously true when $m$ is empty. If it holds for $m$, then consider any $n\in m\cup\{m\}$: either $n\in m$, which implies $n\subset m$ by induction hypothesis; or $n\in\{m\}$, which implies $n=m\subset m\cup\{m\}$. Hence done.

---

**Claim**: For natural numbers $m,n, n\subset m\text{ and }n\neq m\Rightarrow n\in m$.

*Proof*: Base case: vacuously true when $m=\emptyset$.

Induction step: assume the claim holds for $m$, we now prove it holds for $m\cup\{m\}$. Fix any $n\subset m\cup\{m\}$. We divide into two cases: $m\in n$ and $m\notin n$.

If $m\in n$, this is where the lemma is used: we immediately get $m\subset n$. But $m\in n$ means $\{m\}\subset n$, so $m\cup\{m\}\subset n$, hence $n=m\cup\{m\}$, a contradiction.

If $m\notin n$, then $n\subset m$, so $n\in m$ by induction hypothesis, in particular $n\in m\cup\{m\}$ and we're done.

---

By the way, I suggest you rewrite the definition of $W$ as $W=\{n\in\omega:(n\in m)\vee (m\in n)\vee (n=m)\}$ which is logically equivalent and shows the trichotomy clearer.

Comment: what allows you to say “If $m\not\in n$, then $n\subset m$”?

Comment: thank you for the answer. i think however, it would be best for me to consider cases where $n\subseteq m$ or $n\subseteq\{m\}$. In the latter case, if $n$ is non-empty, then you run into issues with the axiom of regularity, so $n$ has to be empty in that case, and $\emptyset\in m\cup\{m\}$. If $n\subset m$, then by IH, $n\in m\subset m\cup\{m\}$. If $n=m$, then $n\in m\cup\{m\}$. Done. Can't believe I didn't see this before. Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: 1. $m\notin n\Rightarrow n\subset m$ follows from the fact that $n\subset m\cup\{m\}$.

Comment: 2. I find your proof kind of problematic. Note that $A\subset B\cup C$ **does not** imply $A\subset B$ or $A\subset C$ (for instance, $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,3\},C=\{2\}$. In this case, it is (somewhat) vacuously the case because, if you follow my proof, $n\subset\{m\}$ is impossible. But you cannot just say $n\subset m$ or $n\subset\{m\}$ without justification.

Comment: 1. i didn’t piece that together until you said it. 2. thanks for pointing out that error. resorted to that because i really couldn’t see how $m\notin n\rightarrow n\subset m$. as a follow up question, how are the two cases $m\in n$ or $m\not\in n$ exhaustive? is it just that given any sets $x$ and $y$, either $x\in y$ or $x\not\in y$?

Comment: Yes, $\notin$ should be defined as the logical negation of $\in$. Set theory is built on the observation that one (total) relation $\in$ suffices to do a lot of maths; as a result we must be able to determine whether $x\in y$ is true or false for any sets $x,y$. These correspond to $x\in y,x\notin y$, respectively.